# Are questions about what laws should be instituted on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'd like to ask if people think a law should be instituted in certain circumstances. Is that an acceptable question on the Law site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That might be a good question for Philosophy or Politics SE, but not for Law. It is essentially outside the scope of law, which is the descriptive field of "saying what the law is". That would include questions about the logical mechanics of a hypothetical law, such as "Would a law X be constitutional, in light of the First Amendment". There is no *legal* standard for judging whether a given law *should* exist, so there is no objective standard for deciding whether the correct answer is "yes" or "no". If you have a specific issue in mind, you might ask about it on Meta and we could make suggestions about how to avail closure based on the question being a call for opinions (frowny face).

Comment: How about an extension or a stronger version of an existing law?

Comment: Same issue. Suppose the proposal is to impose life imprisonment for possession of marijuana, strengthening the existing law. Should we strengthen the law? The answer lies in what you think the function of government is. If the function of government is to protect people from self harm, then yes; if the function of government is to protect people from initiation of force, then no. These are political questions, not legal ones.

Comment: I tend to agree. There's a tenuous line between [politics.se] and [law.se], and quite often when questions on our site become a bit too... opinionated, they might be better there (but check their guidelines first)